# How to shuffle words in a sentence?

Tags: php

I have a simple form where I can enter a sentence. When I submit the form I want to shuffle the words (not characters). This is what I did so far, but it's not mixing the words:

```
if (isset($_POST['sentence'])) {

    $original_sentence = $_POST['sentence'];

} else {

    die ('Give me a sentence!');

}


$words = explode( " / ", $original_sentence );


foreach($words as $word) {
    array_rand($words); 
    echo $word;
}
```

Comment: `$words = explode(" ", $original_sentence); shuffle($words); var_dump($words);`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+shuffle+array

Answer (score 1):

you can explode, shuffle and implode:

```
$original_sentence = "i am a simple sentence";
$words = explode( " ", $original_sentence );
shuffle($words);
echo implode(" ",$words);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php